# Accessing global site regions in Piranha CMS

Tags: piranha-cms

I have added a global site region to my site and filled it with some content. How can I read this content from page view and/or layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature differs a bit between WebPages & MVC, the reason for this being that in WebPages (like WebForms) a Layout-page have a different model than the actual page being executed. If you use WebPages you simply add the following line first in the Layout page:

```
@inherits Piranha.WebPages.LayoutPage
```

This will automatically load the layout page model and all the global regions.

If you're using **MVC** this can't be done automatically as the Layout doesn't have a model. You can simply add the following in your Layout-page:

```
@{
  Piranha.Models.PageModel global;

  if (HttpContext.Current.Items["Piranha_CurrentPage"] != null) {
    var current = 
      (Piranha.Models.Page)HttpContext.Current.Items["Piranha_CurrentPage"];

    global = Piranha.Models.PageModel.GetBySite(current.SiteTreeId);
  } else {
    global = Piranha.Models.PageModel.GetBySite(Piranha.Config.SiteTreeId);
  }
}
```

This snippet loads the layout page from:

1. If it's a page is displayed it loads the site tree the page is contained in
2. If it's a post it loads the site tree from the current site.

Hope this helps you!

Regards

/Håkan

Comment: HttpContext needs .Current after it if this is on the view. Also the cast should be Piranha.Models.Page, not Piranha.Models.PageModel. PageModel does not contain the SiteTreeId property. :)

Comment: Thanks! I must have had a bad day :)